# Get updated grid data using JQGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using JQGrid framework for displaying grid data. There are two grids and data will be draggable from grid 1 to grid2 and from grid2 to grid 1. I want to get the updated grid 2 data after removing or adding some elements into the grid. Please help me. I am new to this framework.

code:

HMTL:

```
<input id="updateName" type="button" onclick="updateName();" value="Update">

function updateName(){
    var selectedData = $("#jqGrid2").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data");
    var selData = $.map(selectedData, function (item) { return item.selectedData; });

....
}
```

colmodel:

```
jQuery("#jqGrid2").jqGrid({ 
                    datatype: "local",
                    data: datagrid2,
                    rowNum :200,
                    width : 450,
                    height: 100, 
                    shrinkToFit: false,
                    forceFit: true,
                    colModel: [
                        { label: 'Student Name', name: 'selectedData', index: 'selectedData', width: 450, align: 'left'}
                    ],
                    gridComplete: function(){
                                        jQuery('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').css({'height':'200px', 'max-height':'200px'});    
                        jQuery('.ui-th-column').css({'background':'#F2F2F2','height':'25px','text-align':'left'});
                        jQuery('.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td').css({'height':'20px'});
                        $(this).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow").removeClass("myAltRowClassEven myAltRowClassOdd");
                        $(this).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow:odd").addClass("myAltRowClassEven");
                         $(this).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow:even").addClass("myAltRowClassOdd");
                         $('.ui-corner-all').addClass('ui-zero-corner');
                    },
                    onSortCol: function (index, columnIndex, sortOrder) {
                         $(this).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow").removeClass("myAltRowClassEven myAltRowClassOdd");
                         $(this).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow:odd").addClass("myAltRowClassEven");
                         $(this).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow:even").addClass("myAltRowClassOdd");
                        //return 'stop';
                    }

                });

                jQuery("#jqGrid1").jqGrid('gridDnD',{connectWith:'#jqGrid2'}); 
                jQuery("#jqGrid2").jqGrid('gridDnD',{connectWith:'#jqGrid1'});
```

I am using the above code to get the data. But the problem is while adding the data everything is fine as expected.But while removing the data i.e dragging to another column(Grid1) the data must be removed.If I remove 1 product its fine but if I try to remove all the elements in the grid at once I am stil getting the values from the grid2.

Comment: Please include in every your question about jqGrid the information about the version of jqGrid which you use (or which you can use) and the fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). If you new with jqGrid then I would recommend you to use the latest (currently 4.13.4) version of free jqGrid. It's the fork, which I develop. It's compatible with old jqGrid 4.7. Look at the information from [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) too.

Comment: I am using the JQGrid version 4.5.2 @Oleg

Comment: @Oleg I have added the code and explanation. Need some help. Thanks

Comment: @Oleg added more explanation. Please let me know if you need any more info I will post it.

Comment: @Oleg I have updated the code once again.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you use `datatype: "local"` in both grids. You can get the current (modified) data by the usage `$("#gridid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data")`, where `#gridid` should be the id selector of the grid1 or grid2.

Comment: Hi.Thanks for the reply. I am using that code but that returns an object which I need o conevert hat into JSON stirng. I am getting null if I do that. @Oleg

Comment: @SRM: Sorry, but it's difficult to follow you. It's important *where* in your code you place `$("#gridid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data")`. Could you append the text of your question with the JavaScript code, which show your current usage of `.jqGrid("getGridParam", "data")`? More better would be if you provide the demo, which reproduces your current problem.

Comment: I have added the code and explanation.Please need some help.

Comment: @SRM: It's unclear *when* the code will be executed, `item.selectedData` (see the callback `$.map`) will work only if you have the column with the `name: "selectedData"`. Thus you should post `colModel` too. It's better just to use `console.log(selectedData);` and to examine the `$("#jqGrid2").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data")` in the console. In any way you should post much more long code fragment to allow other to help you.

Comment: I have added more explanation. Please let me know if you need more information. When use drag option from grid 2 to grid1 the data is still showing some elements even after dragging all the elements.If I drag 1 element the data is fine.Need some solution to this.

Comment: @SRM: The HTML page should have additionally some element, like button "Save Results", which the user should be able to click. You should include the code with `$("#jqGrid2").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data")` inside of `click` event handler. The current code, which you posted don't show **where** or **when** you try to use `$("#jqGrid2").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data")`.

Comment: I have added the HTML code.On clicking the  update Studentname button we need the data rom the grid.

Comment: @SRM: Try the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/c3q9b4f4/. I see no problem.